# Unix for loop and grep combined ksh hp-ux

Tags: shell-script, ksh, hp-ux

What if you have 5 or 6 files, specific files .biz in a directory, and you want to store them one at the time in a variable $file, and apply a set of command  until no more .biz file are found in the directory.

I tried to use

```
for f in graham/quant
do
  if grep  "max" $file;
  then
    maximum.sh $file
  elif grep  "milan" $file;
  then
    milan.sh $file
  elif grep  "min" $file;
  then
    minimum.sh $file
  .
  .
  .
  else
     echo " keep working you are close "
  fi
done
```

but the program executes all the files with the first valid condition.

If you have 5 files with .biz extension, all of them will be executed with first valid condition 5 times.

the output will be :

```
  Milan
  Milan
  Milan
  Milan
  Milan
```

instead of

```
  Milan
  Minimum
  Maximum
  .
  .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: for f in graham/quant/*.biz; do?

Comment: better yet for file in graham/quant/*.biz

Comment: *.biz will just  count the number of files you have in the folder and then run the loop according to that amount, the output will still be identical.

Comment: You're mistaken about it. The for statement like i wrote in bash script will not increase f as you are thinking. it will fill it with the file name one by one in the loop.

Comment: Out of 10 scripts in a directory I'm trying to call a script base on what a file holds. If you have 5 .biz files, the  program will store each file in a variable $file one at the time and the grep look into $file and return yes or no if the file holds a word: " if grep -q "max" $file;".
If yes then  the program execute a command. The key here is .biz files hold different words, I thought about using a case statement to make that more elegant. My main issue  is, how to store the files in a variable  one at the time so the grep can look into each of them individually.

Comment: @Driven Your program doesn't loop at all.  `file=$(ls *.biz)` stores all the files in "$file" at the same time, so that `grep -q "max" $file` is the same as `grep -q "max" file1.biz file2.biz file3.biz`.   It succeeds if _any_ of them contain "max", and then runs `maximum file1.biz file2.biz file3.biz`.

Comment: If you want to look one by one individually with grep do exactly like i say in the answer! The for loop will load the $file variable with the individual file name for each loop. Do you understand now or there is something that i missing?

Comment: more like if you have the word rim in file1.biz  rim---->file1.biz    ted in file2.biz ted---->file2.biz. both files are in the directory and the script will store file1.biz in a variable. grep file1.biz for a word and execute a command if file1.biz holds the word.

Comment: @Luciano Andress Martini unfortunatly it's not working .

Comment: grep: can't open maximum.biz  milan.biz  minimum.biz

Comment: @Luciano Andress Martini also you are missing the variable you use for holding the the file.

Comment: @Driven: please use the answer's own comment section to leave comments about that answer

Comment: what do the `max.sh`, `milan.sh` and `min.sh` scripts do?  from your example, it seems that they only print `Maximum`, `Milan`, or `Minimum`...is that **all** that they do?

Comment: @cas Yes! You are right, just for the test it will display  which scripts the program called. In reality they caculate the maximum the minimum and the average. .biz is a statistic file with a set of numbers. When a .biz file is generated it comes with its purposes. A .biz file can be generated for maximum, minimum, median, average, mid-range, total-range, rank and  midpoint... Maximum, Milan, and Minimum are the one we use the most. Your help will be really appreciated, Thank you

Comment: @Driven will you please [edit] your question to include this extra information. Stop drip-feeding it to us in the comments.

Comment: @roaima no need to be disrespectful by exhibiting your lack of manners and social illiteracy. In case you haven't noticed, I'm new like very very new to this forum. Although I'm totally grateful for all the help I got so far on this forum. I, myself will never let some senseless individual using some degrading comment,  just because they can hide behind a keyboard.  Thank you

Comment: There are three comments in this thread where you have added a little extra information each time. It gets frustrating when someone - new or otherwise - spreads useful detail out across the comment field. I'm sorry to hear you found my request disrespectful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the users says it is using **an ancient unix shell**, lets try another version of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#test version for ancient shell. 
cd graham/quant
for file in *.biz
do
  grep -q "max" "$file"  
  if [ "$?" = "0"  ]; then
       maximum.sh "$file"
  fi

  grep -q "milan" "$file"
  if [ "$?" = "0"  ]; then
       milan.sh "$file"
  fi

  grep -q "min" "$file"
  if [ "$?" = "0"  ]; then
       minimum.sh "$file"
  fi


done
cd $OLDPWD
```

Comment: grep: can't open maximum.biz milan.biz minimum.biz, also you are missing the variable you use for holding the file.

Comment: The variable is $file. It is loaded by for. I think you are not using bash so we are programming in different languages i tested the script and it works nice.

Comment: Yeah!!! I'm using both but I'm testing that on Ksh

Comment: On ksh it will not work, i wrote this code for bash, ksh is not compatible with it.

Comment: there's nothing in your script that won't work with either bash or ksh.  or any bourne-like sh.

Comment: I never tested in others bourne-like sh. I cant understand why nothing is a solution for him maybe he is using an ancient unix version?

Comment: @Driven did you test this exactly as posted, or did you modify it? In particular, do you still have your `file="$(ls *.biz)"` or similar?

Comment: thanks a lot all for your responses, but I'm having the feeling that my HP_UX ksh shell really needs some updates. I will take a different route and update the topic

Comment: Is bash available in HP_UX? if it is consider to use it, or perhaps the ancient Unix Shell (sh), I dont how old are your system, but i think this another syntax maybe solve your problem try this new version. I am updating it.

Comment: Try again friend. Its working now? If it is not i will adjust it more, i dont remember how to program using sh! My contact with it are for a very short while.

Comment: @luciano andress martini fantastic you nailed it buddy. Worked like a charmed. I was planning to use a case statement instead. Can't complain of the outcome. Again thank you.

Comment: I am very happy to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -lZ max   graham/quant/*.biz | xargs -0r maximum.sh
grep -lZ milan graham/quant/*.biz | xargs -0r milan.sh
grep -lZ min   graham/quant/*.biz | xargs -0r minimum.sh
```

Note: requires GNU `grep` for the `-Z` option to output NUL-separated filenames.

These lines use `grep`'s `-l` option to output a list of files containing the wanted pattern (`max`, `milan`, or `min`), and the `-Z` option to use NULs to separate the filenames (so that it is safe to use with filenames with **any** valid characters).

This is piped into `xargs` to run the appropriate script for each matching file.

It is assumed that these scripts can correctly handle multiple filename arguments on the command line.  If not, add `-n 1` to the `xargs` options.

e.g. `grep -lZ max   graham/quant/*.biz | xargs -0r -n 1 maximum.sh`

From `man grep`:

> `-l`, `--files-with-matches`
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.

and:

> `-Z`, `--null`
>
> Output a zero byte (the ASCII  NUL  character)  instead  of  the character  that normally follows a file name.  For example, `grep -lZ` outputs a zero byte after each  file  name  instead  of  the usual  newline.
>
> This option makes the output unambiguous, even in the presence of file names containing unusual characters like newlines.
>
> This  option  can  be  used  with commands like `find -print0`, `perl -0`, `sort -z`, and  `xargs -0`  to  process  arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I'm using Ksh                                                  -  grep: can't open graham/quant/*.biz
-  xargs: unknown option: xargs
-  xargs: unknown option: -0r

Comment: ksh is irrelevant here.  Those commands will work in bash or ksh or any shell.  What kind of unix are you using?  Obviously not a mainstream linux distro, because you don't have GNU xargs.  Don't reply in a comment here, add the info to your question...use a tag if there's a matching one (like `/ksh`, `/solaris`, `/aix` or whatever).  If you don't provide relevant and necessary information, you can't expect to get an answer that's specific to your environment.  BTW, I'm beginning to think that you are trying to do something with several sh scripts that can easily be done with one awk script.

Comment: thanks a lot all for your responses, but I'm having the feeling that my HP_UX ksh shell really needs some updates. I will take a different route and update the topic

Comment: Try the commands in my answer **without** the `-Z` option in `grep` and **without** the `-0r` option in `xargs`.  e.g. `grep -l max   graham/quant/*.biz | xargs maximum.sh`.  The only difference is that it won't work properly if your filenames contain space or newline characters.  And if `grep` complains about not being able to find or open `graham/quant/*.biz` - specify the **correct** path etc to your files.  and update  your question to let us know what the correct path/filenames are too.